# What is the right way to create Datastore Entity and use it in Dataflow pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

Which of these is the correct / preferred way to create Datastore Entity:

```
    // First, create a fake email for our fake user
    final String email = "me@fake.com";

    // Now, create a 'key' for that user using the email
    final Key userKey =
            datastore.newKeyFactory().kind("user").newKey(email);

    // Now create a entity using that key adn add some fields to it
    final Entity newUser =
            Entity
                    .builder(userKey)
                    .set("name", "Faker")
                    .set("email", email)
                    .build();
```

or like it's done in DatastoreWordCount [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/DatastoreWordCount.java) ?

- Entity from the first example is `com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity`.
- Entity from the second example is `com.google.datastore.v1.Entity`.

I have code using `com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity` and I don't know how to store it Datastore as a part of Dataflow pipeline, since all code examples I found online suggest:

```
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreIO.v1().write()
```

but it's only working with `com.google.datastore.v1.Entity`.

I'm using `com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:1.7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have analyzed the situation well - Dataflow's `DatastoreIO.v1()` works with `com.google.datastore.v1.Entity`.

Comment: Is there any way to create default key for entity in Dataflow like we can create in Google Datastore for an entity, without proving any manual id or name for the key.